# TextViews Changed position in Arabic Language Devices

Tags: java, android, layout

I designed a layout that has two TextViews beside each other and they were positioned correctly in my emulator and my physical device as I am using English Language.

However, when I saw the app in an Arabic device, The TextViews exchanged positioned. What was in the right went to the left and vice versa.[!

Any idea of how to fix the positions regardless of what the language of the device is?

Comment: you need the text to stay in one postion in any language??

Comment: I want it to be fixed in all languages no matter what the device is using.

Comment: Why dont you  use  weight for both textview using linearlayout

Comment: How can I use weight and what it is?

Answer (score 5):

When a user chooses a right-to-left language, certain Android components will automatically reverse their order (like `LinearLayout`, or `ConstraintLayout` if you're using start/end instead of just left/right).

If you want to *disable* this feature, so that items are *always* laid out left-to-right regardless of the user's language choice, add this line to the `<application>` tag in your manifest:

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Comment: As a note:  you probably do not want to disable this feature.  THis is what their users expect. And if you're using a layout like RelativeLayout, you want to use toStartOf/toEndOf and alignStart/alignEnd rather than left/right to make it work there too.  Not doing this usually makes your app look unprofessional and poor quality compared ot correctly localized apps.

Comment: It worked with the above in the manifest. However, all textviews became left aligned!... Even though they are centered in my layout